# Has the Hulk ever broken a bone?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I've read quite a few Hulk comics / comics where Hulk makes a guest appearance and AFAIK, he's never broken a bone in a fight, or at least it's never been made really obvious that he has.

I guess he'd have to fight someone insanely strong, [Silver Surfer](http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs44/f/2009/153/f/2/Silver_Surfer_2008_by_Eamonodonoghue.jpg), [The Thing](http://cartoon.mthai.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/tumblr_mb7z0nCt5s1rbafx6o1_1280.jpg) or [Thanos](http://www.cinemablend.com/images/news_img/42725/Thanos_42725.jpg) maybe.

**Has anyone seen a very clear example of someone breaking one of the Hulk's bones?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's broken plenty - oh, you mean *his own* bones? I don't know.

Comment: The Hulk heals FAST, and he's very tough (in a mental sense).  Odds are he breaks them frequently when he faces enemies of a certain caliber, but shrugs it off until it heals a few minutes later.

Comment: @Nerrolken yeah that's kinda what I thought, so I asked for _a very clear example of someone breaking one of the Hulk's bones_.

Comment: @Daft I know you did, that's why I commented instead of answering...

Comment: @Nerrolken well then we're both right!

Comment: In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, Ironman knocked him badly and he was seen spitting out his tooth.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 I appreciate the title edit suggestion, but proper English would be appreciated.

Comment: @Daft It may be correct, but it's confusing.

Comment: Is Silver Surfer really that strong to break Hulk?

Comment: @Parto [He sure is](http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--nFT51dsy--/c_fit,fl_progressive,q_80,w_636/ntzusdhnlksoni73egbb.jpg).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In a word, yes. In "[Future Imperfect #2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maestro_%28comics%29)", the Hulk's neck gets snapped by the Maestro. He requires several days to fully recover.

[image]

[image]

---

He also suffers a broken leg during the [Secret Wars](http://www.supermegamonkey.net/chronocomic/entries/marvel_super_heroes_secret_war.shtml) crossover event, fighting against Ultron

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, when the whole panel is formatted in the shape of the word "KRAK", methinks that's undeniably a broken bone.  Nice one!

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for Richard!

Comment: Mmmm, a spinal cord injury does not necessarily mean a broken bone.  And in the second example, it looks like his leg got zapped, not actually broken.  Although the crutch/leg-brace are fitting.

Comment: @imallett can you read bro? **KRAK**

Comment: Maestro: [Snapping necks and cashing cheques](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzdll4zFkp4)!

Answer (score 21):

#### The Hulk doesn't get many broken bones due to his heightened regenerative abilities. He regenerates so fast, most injuries don't have the time to come into existence before his body repairs them. This appears to apply primarily to the Green and Red male Hulks. The She-Hulk versions of those characters aren't quite as resilient.

- To damage the Hulk in any way, let alone breaking bones, you have to first be able to overcome his regeneration. In a battle against Vector, whose power stripped the flesh from the Bones of the Hulk, he was able to, in a matter of seconds, regenerate all of that damaged flesh even while flayed to the BONE!

[image]

- With that understood, to break the Hulk's bones, you have to be as strong as the Hulk and be able to apply pressure or force sufficient to break his bones and continue to apply that force. It takes someone whose strength ranks at the highest levels of physical or psychic force possible and that is a short list.
- It would take people whose powers are considered near-cosmic or cosmic to be able to lay claim to delivering such injuries. Any of Earth's **[All-Fathers/Mothers](https://marvel.fandom.com/All-Father)**, **[Ultron](https://marvel.fandom.com/Ultron)**, **[Gladiator (Shiar)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladiator_%28Kallark%29)**, **[Sentry](https://marvel.fandom.com/Robert_Reynolds_%28Earth-616%29)**, **[Onslaught](https://marvel.fandom.com/Onslaught_(Psychic_Entity)_(Earth-616))** (psychic entity composed of Xavier and Magneto's powers), **[Silver Surfer](https://marvel.fandom.com/Silver_Surfer)** (or any of the more powerful heralds of Galactus) or someone imbued with the **[Captain Universe](https://marvel.fandom.com/Captain_Universe)** or **[Phoenix-force](https://marvel.fandom.com/Phoenix)** powers.

[image]

*A demonstration of Prince Namor imbued with one-fifth of the Phoenix-Force was sufficient to clearly break the Red Hulk's arm. A clear demonstration that IT CAN BE DONE!*

- A recent break of the Hulk's arm is done by the Red Hulk. It doesn't stay broken long and the fight is as so many of them are, inconclusive. It is only because the Red Hulk has the Hulk in a position where the Hulk has less leverage allows him to break the Hulk's arm.

[image]

- During the Avengers vs X-men storyline, Colossus, as the Avatar of Cyttorak, beat the Red Hulk to a pulp, breaking bones at will.

[image]

Comment: I could be mistaken but I'm fairly sure that last picture is from Avengers vs X-men not Fear itself. This fight is taking place at utopia

Comment: Nitpick: The kind of grip Prince Namor applies here usually breaks / dislocates the wrist, not the arm itself. But KRACK indeed, and I can vouch for the NNYYAAAGGHH!! as well. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's not quite a broken bone, (or it could be but it's not as definitive as you're asking for), but the closest I've seen is during the climax fight of *The Incredible Hulk* film:

At around 9:40 in that clip, after he has defeated Abomination, Hulk very clearly *snaps* his shoulder back into place before roaring triumphantly.  Obviously, his shoulder had been pulled out of its socket at least, possibly broken as well.  Given the actions he was taking during the fight, it's tough to pinpoint exactly what did it, but he was clearly fighting through his injury for a portion of the scene.

(I might be over-analyzing, but he does seem to be favoring one arm for the last portion of the fight, hitting with his right and simply holding on with his injured left.  You can almost see some skeletal distortion his left shoulder during the final moments, but I might be making that up.)

I'm less familiar with the comics universe, but in the MCU, that's as close as we've come to seeing the Hulk injured, in a skeletal sense.  It's not for-sure a broken bone, but it's definitely possible that his shoulder or arm was broken in that fight.

Comment: It's funny, that's actually the scene that first got me wondering if he had ever broken a bone in the comics!

Comment: Video has been taken down.