# Can the Hulk lose and regrow limbs?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

When in green Hulk form, can the Hulk suffer a major injury like losing a limb? Can he regrow limbs and recover from mortal injuries in Hulk form?

Comment: What version of the Hulk are you talking about? He's been depicted in 4 live-action TV shows, 11 feature films, 17 animated shows and more than ten thousand comic serials including nine of his own titles

Comment: I don't know all of the Hulk depictions and if his superpowers vary considerably or not. I guess an answer would refer to the several most common versions and answer to each case.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to swallow the ocean. His abilities in [his most popular comic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Hulk) vary ***vastly*** from his [most popular depiction in film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9LOoGOyLx4), for example.

Comment: Aside from the issue of which medium/s you're asking about, in the Earth-616 comics alone, there are multiple green Hulk versions, such as the Savage Hulk, the Merged/Professor Hulk, and Devil/Immortal Hulk. Do you want answers for all of those incarnations, or just the Savage Hulk (i.e. the 'classic' green Hulk) specifically?

Comment: I didn't know there was such much variety in Hulk incarnations. What about bracketing the answer between the weakest Hulk to the strongest Hulk and taking the MCU Hulk in-between?

Comment: Duplicate? - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87396/has-the-hulk-ever-broken-a-bone/87401#87401 or https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/is-the-hulk-immortal/20901#20901

Comment: @Paulie_D This answers my question, and the answer is "yes". It is nearly impossible to cut Hulk's limbs, but when he loses one, his regeneration power quickly regrows it.

Comment: Immortal Hulk is literally chopped into pieces, and not only can he regenerate, but can actually control the bits not connected to him like a zombie.

Comment: I mean, I can do the first part.